# Artikel bei Aufzählungen von Substantiven, die das gleiche Genus haben, ja oder nein?

Tags: article

ich habe eine Frage, bei folgendem Satz:

> ... Bewertung der Qualität, Effektivität und Effizienz ...

Kann man Artikel weglassen oder nicht? Ich habe bei Google recherchiert:

- "der Qualität, der Effektivität und der Effizienz" kommt 40.000 vor.
- "der Qualität, Effektivität und Effizienz" kommt 60.000 vor.

Als ich nach Regeln geschaut habe, habe ich gefunden:

> "Bei Aufzählungen von Substantiven, die das gleiche Genus haben, wird sehr oft der Artikel nur beim ersten Substantiv gesetzt. Das ist häufig nicht richtig und ergibt im Fehlerfall sinnentstellende Veränderungen."

Ich kenne mich jetzt nicht aus ... Kann es mir jemand erklären?

Comment: Hallo Dagmar und Herzlich Willkommen auf german.stackexchange! Wo hast du diese Regel denn gefunden? Ob etwas "falsch" oder "richtig" ist, ist in Bezug auf Sprache oft gar nicht so leicht zu beantworten, und hängt davon ab, welche Autorität man anerkennt. In welchem Kontext ist es dir wichtig, dass es richtig oder falsch ist? Musst du als Beamte einen Text für eine Behörde schreiben oder eine Institution nach außen vertreten? Musst du Besserwisser beeindrucken? Oder geht es dir nur darum, nicht missverstanden zu werden? https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen

Answer (score 2):

Mein Sprachgefühl und das, was ich in der Schule gelernt habe, sagen genau das Gegenteil.
Ich hätte Deinen Beispielsatz genauso formuliert:

> .. Bewertung der Qualität, Effektivität und Effizienz ...

Die Wiederholung des Artikels wäre mir "umständlich" und "unnötig" erschienen.

Wegen des gefühlten Widerspruchs wollte ich wissen, woher die Aussage aus dem Zitat kommt.
Google ergab [diesen Link](http://hauptplatz.unipohl.de/Artikel.htm) als Ursprung des Zitats.

Die Aussage wird in dem Artikel weiter erklärt und mit Beispielen untermauert. Hier das erste Beispiel:

> **Es kam zu einer Aussprache mit dem Betriebsleiter und Personalchef.**
>
> Der Satz bedeutet zweifelsfrei, daß der Betriebsleiter auch gleichzeitig Personalchef ist. Das ist in der Regel nicht der Fall. Wenn es aber nicht gemeint ist, muß es heißen:
>
> **Es kam zu einer Aussprache mit dem Betriebsleiter und dem Personalchef.**

Diesem Beispiel kann ich zu 100% folgen, denn hier findet tatsächlich durch Auslassen des Artikels eine Bedeutungsverschiebung statt.

Und nun muss man sich noch einmal die Aussage Deines Zitats anschauen:

> Das ist **häufig** nicht richtig und ergibt im **Fehlerfall** sinnentstellende Veränderungen

Diese Aussage ist nicht so absolut, wie Du sie verstanden hast. Hier steht nicht, dass das **meistens** nicht richtig ist sondern eben nur **häufig**...

Ich verstehe den Satz als warnenden Hinweis, dass man beim Weglassen der Aufzählungsartikel zumindest kurz über solche Bedeutungsverschiebungen nachdenken sollte und sie nicht gedankenlos verwendet.

Doch gerade bei eher abstrakten Begriffen wie "Qualität", "Effektivität" und "Effizient", ist die Chance, eine solche Verschiebung unbeabsichtigt herzustellen eher gering.

Answer (score 0):

Quellenangaben können oft helfen, Missverständnisse zu klären. Ich habe die von dir zitierte Regel hier gefunden: http://hauptplatz.unipohl.de/Artikel.htm

Ich zitiere mal ein Beispiel von dieser Seite:

> > Es kam zu einer Aussprache mit dem Betriebsleiter und Personalchef.
>
> Der Satz bedeutet zweifelsfrei, daß der Betriebsleiter auch gleichzeitig Personalchef ist. Das ist in der Regel nicht der Fall. Wenn es aber nicht gemeint ist, muß es heißen:
>
> > Es kam zu einer Aussprache mit dem Betriebsleiter und dem Personalchef.

Grundlegend ist mal zu sagen, dass man bei Seiten, die auch noch im Jahr 2020 Rechtschreibregeln verwenden, die vor 1996 gegolten haben (erkennbar z.B. an Wort »daß« statt »dass«), vorsichtig sein sollte.

Davon abgesehen, ist das Beispiel aber durchaus korrekt, weil *»Betriebsleiter«* und *»Personalchef«* Bezeichnungen von Rollen sind, die von derselben Person oder von zwei verschiedenen Personen wahrgenommen werden können, und hier ist das Weglassen bzw. Verwenden des zweiten Artikels ein Hinweis darauf, welche der beiden Möglichkeiten zutrifft.

Ich finde aber nur zwei Seiten, in denen die Wortfolge *»Bewertung der Qualität, Effektivität und Effizienz«* vorkommt, nämlich:

- https://prezi.com/sx6ozguufxeo/alex/

  > Erfolgskontrolle ​​
  >
  > - **Bewertung der Qualität, Effektivität und Effizienz** der Hilfen
  > - Informationen über Krankheitsbild
- https://www.baua.de/DE/Angebote/Publikationen/Schriftenreihe/Forschungsberichte/2004/Fb1021.html

  > Weitere Ergebnisse sind die Bewertungen der identifizierten Betreuungsmodelle anhand von Expertenaussagen sowie ein Set von sieben Indikatoren, die jeweils durch mehrere Parameter untersetzt sind, zur **Bewertung der Qualität, Effektivität und Effektivität** einer betriebsärztlichen Betreuung.

Da in beiden Fällen keine Gefahr besteht, dass es durch die Verwendung von Artikeln zu Bedeutungsverschiebungen kommt, ist es in beiden Beispielen völlig unproblematisch die Artikel wegzulassen. Weil dadurch der Lesefluss steigt, rate ich sogar dazu, die Artikel wegzulassen.

Für die Versionen, bei der auch *»Effektivität«* und *»Effektivität«* mit Artikel verwendet werden, finde ich gar keine Seiten.

---

Zu Regeln generell:

In der deutschen Sprache ist nur die Orthographie (= Rechtschreibung) genormt. Die Orthographie regelt, wie man Buchstaben anordnen muss, damit daraus gültige Wörter entstehen. Wenn man Wörter anordnet, um damit Sätze zu bilden, befindet man sich nicht mehr im Wirkungsfeld der Orthographie. Man ist dann im Reich der Grammatik. Orthographie und Grammatik sind einander zwar in einigen Dingen ähnlich (beides sind syntaktische Regelwerke), aber davon ist eben nur die Orthographie genormt.

Für die Grammatik (und darum geht es in der vorliegenden Fragestellung) gibt es aber keine Instanz oder Behörde, die per normativer Verordnung festlegen dürfte/könnte/sollte was richtig oder falsch ist. Das, was bei der Grammatik normativ wirkt, ist tatsächlich "nur" die vielzitierte normative Kraft des Faktischen.

Mit anderen Worten: Genau das ist richtig, was die Mehrheit macht.

Regeln, die in Grammatikbüchern stehen, sind der Versuch darzustellen, wie die Mehrheit die Sprache verwendet. Das hilft jenen, die die Sprache erlernen wollen, ist aber nicht dafür gedacht, jenen, die die Sprache verwenden, Vorschriften zu machen.