# Aufzählung und Artikel

Tags: article, conjunction

Fehlt in dem folgenden Satz nicht ein "die" vor "*daraus resultierend*"?

> Hintergrund dieser hohen Anzahl sind die arbeitsseitig hohen
> Anforderungen und *daraus resultierenden* Anforderungsstandards.

Also obwohl da "daraus resultierenden" steht, kann man den Artikel weglassen? Es geht hier nicht darum ob man schreiben darf "*ich mag die Äpfel, Birnen und Orangen*". Es geht um den "Einschub" (oder was auch immer das ist) "*daraus resultierenden*".

Kann man hier eine allgemeine Regel finden, wann ein Artikel in einer Aufzählung notwendig ist und wann nicht? Ich bin hier insbesondere unschlüssig wegen des "daraus", was für mich die Aufzählung irgendwie unterbricht.

Comment: Vielleicht hilft dir https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61140/artikel-bei-aufzählungen-von-substantiven-die-das-gleiche-genus-haben-ja-oder weiter? Nachfolgende Artikel können bei Aufzählungen weggelassen werden, sofern er redundant ist und der Sinn eindeutig erhalten bleibt.

Comment: Die Frage ist insofern kein Duplikat, dass das Adjektiv *resultierend* die falsche Flexionsendung trägt, was in der anderen Frage gar nicht thematisiert wird.

Comment: @yetiCGN Wieso sollte mir das weiterhelfen? Ist der Satz so etwa korrekt?

Comment: Ich interpretiere den Satz so, dass der Artikel "die" weggelassen wurde. "Hintergrund dieser hohen Anzahl sind die arbeitsseitig hohen Anforderungen und _die_ daraus resultierenden Anforderungsstandards." Dadurch würde es unmissverständlich. @BjörnFriedrich Ich glaube nicht, dass es "und daraus resultierende" heißen soll/muss, denn der Nebensatz erklärt weiter die "hohe Anzahl". SebastianE: Ja, aus meiner Sicht ist der Satz korrekt und ein identischer Artikel wurde weggelassen. "daraus resultierenden" beschreibt *die Anforderungsstandards* genauer, wobei ich auch nicht weiß, wie man das nennt.

Comment: @YetiCGN in einer ähnlichen Frage von mir wurde argumentiert, dass man nur bei "Kategorien" den Artikel weglassen darf, nicht aber bei spezifischen Dingen. In diesem Fall sind die daraus resultierenden "Dinge" jedoch spezifisch, nicht?

Answer (score 1):

Der Satz ist schon richtig so.

Der nur einmal genannte Artikel "die" bezieht sich auf beide Substantive (Anforderungen und Anforderungsstandards), er wird beim zweiten Mal einfach weggelassen, um die unnötige Wiederholung zu vermeiden.

Die auf das grammatisch Wesentliche verkürzte Version des Satzes sieht so aus:

> Hintergrund sind die Anforderungen und Anforderungsstandards.

Das könnte man in dieser kurzen Form noch auf zwei Arten verstehen:

Entweder als "die Anforderungen und die Anforderungsstandards", wobei das zweite "die" als Wiederholung weggelassen wurde.

Oder man versteht es als "die Anforderungen und (irgendwelche) Anforderungsstandards".

Dass in deinem ganzen Beispielsatz die erste Variante gemeint ist, erkennt man aber eindeutig, wenn man die Attribute wieder mit betrachtet:

> die Anforderungsstandards =>
> die resultierenden Anforderungsstandards =>
> die daraus resultierenden Anforderungsstandards

Die Deklination des Attributs (Partizips) "resultierenden" macht in diesem Fall klar, dass ein bestimmter Artikel *die* gemeint ist, sonst würde es "resultierende Anforderungsstandards" heißen.

Das Wort "daraus" ist grammatisch nur eine nähere Bestimmung zu  "resultierenden". (Deshalb kann es auch nicht die Aufzählung unterbrechen.)

Noch ein zweites Beispiel mit ähnlichem Aufbau:

> Andreas liebt die laxen Freitagabende, geschäftigen Samstage und ruhigen Sonntage mit seiner Familie.

Der Artikel *die* ist auch hier dreimal "gemeint", muss aber nicht dreimal wiederholt werden, das erste "die" bezieht sich auf alle drei Tage.

Im Gegensatz dazu:

> Andreas liebt die laxen Freitagabende, geschäftige Samstage und ruhige Sonntage mit seiner Familie.

Hier hat nur der Freitagabend den bestimmten Artikel, die anderen beiden Tage haben keine Artikel, was im Plural dem unbestimmten Artikel entspricht. Das erkennt man, wie in deinem Beispielsatz, nur an der Form der Adjektive.

> *Singular:* der laxe Freitag und ein geschäftiger Samstag
> => *Plural:* die laxen Freitage und geschäftige Samstage

> *Singular:* der laxe Freitag und der geschäftige Samstag 
> => *Plural:* die laxen Freitage und [die] geschäftigen Samstage

Answer (score 0):

Dich scheint zu stören, dass die Semantik des Satzes eine "aus a folgt b"-Eigenschaft, die einen zweiten Artikel erfordern würde, angibt.

Der Grammatik ist allerdings die Semantik des adjektivischen Ausdrucks, der die *Anforderungen* näher beschreibt, vollkommen egal und aus grammatikalischer Sicht ist

> Hintergrund dieser hohen Anzahl sind die arbeitsseitig hohen Anforderungen und **rosaroten** Anforderungsstandards.

ein vollkommen baugleiches Konstrukt, bei dem Ich annehme, dass dich die Auslassung nicht weiter stören würde. Natürlich darf man deshalb den zweiten Artikel weglassen.

Answer (score -2):

Vor "daraus resultierenden" fehlt tatsächlich das **die**.
Sonst klingt der Satz etwas ungewöhnlich, man weiß aber was gemeint ist.

Comment: Ich finde, der Satz klingt keineswegs ungewöhnlich. Es fehlt kein Artikel.