# Artikel weglassen Aufzählung

Tags: article

EDIT: Ich habe den Satz leicht umgestellt (1 Element gelöscht) und Frage leicht verändert.

Warum kann man hier den Artikel "die" beim zweiten Element nicht weglassen.

> Hierzu gehört insbesondere die Sensorik sowie die gesamte 1G Hyperlandschaft.

Comment: Wer sagt, dass man das nicht kann?

Comment: "Die Sensorik, Raumfahrttechnologie sowie gesamte 1G Hyperlandschaft" ist korrektes Deutsch?

Comment: @idmean Man kann, aber es ändert die Bedeutung leicht. Das dritte "die" ist definitiv nicht optional (weil keine Kategorie sondern etwas Spezifisches gemeint ist).

Comment: @SebastianE "Hierzu gehört insbesondere Sensorik, Raumfahrttechnologie sowie die gesamte 1G Hyperlandschaft." wäre korrektes Deutsch, obwohl ich das Verb im Plural verwenden würde..

Comment: @Roland Ich hatte vor kurzem eine ähnliche Frage gestellt und irgendjemand hat sie als Duplikat markiert. Es geht also um die Spezifität? Damals war der Satz "Hintergrund dieser hohen Anzahl sind die arbeitsseitig hohen Anforderungen und daraus resultierenden Anforderungsstandards." Auch hier kann man mE das letzte die nicht weglassen.

Comment: Kategorien können ohne Artikel aufgezählt werden, Individuen und spezifische Objekte nicht. Das Beispiel in Deinem letzten Kommentar ist ebenfalls korrekt. Das "die" bezieht sich dann auf die Gesamtheit der Anforderungen und Standards.

Comment: @Roland Danke. Hast du dazu ggf. eine Quelle, eine schöne Übersicht, eine eigene Antwort o.Ä.?

Comment: Soll das ein Update von https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67276/34192 sein?

Comment: Die "1G-Hyperlandschaft" braucht übrigens einen Bindestrich.

Answer (score 1):

Zunächst einmal: Es ist nicht falsch, "die" wegzulassen, nur unüblich.

Wie in @Rolands Kommentar gilt: Bei Aufzählungen im Singular wird der Artikel nur weggelassen, wenn es um Abstrakta geht. Der Grund ist wahrscheinlich, dass es reiner Zufall ist, ob zwei Nomen in Aufzählungen das gleiche Geschlecht haben. Es wäre ein kognitiver Aufwand, jedes Mal zu prüfen, ob das Geschlecht der Aufzählung mit dem Geschlecht des nächsten Nomens übereinstimmt.

Abstrakta bilden eine Ausnahme, da sie erstens relativ regelmäßig weiblich sind. Zweitens besteht eine Aufzählung aus Abstrakta meist ausschließlich aus Abstrakta, es gibt also nur eine geringe "Gefahr", dass ein nicht weibliches Wort kommt.

Es wäre also wahrscheinlich auch

> Hierzu gehört insbesondere die Sensorik und gesamte 1G-Technologie.

Bei anderen Kategorien, wo das Geschlecht vorhersagbar ist, wie z.B. Berufsbezeichnungen, tritt das nicht auf, da auch das jeweils andere Geschlecht auftauchen kann.

> Der Bauer und der Ritter (und die Prinzessin)

Bei Aufzählungen im Plural hat man das Problem mit dem Geschlecht nicht mehr, hier wird normalerweise der Artikel weggelassen, außer natürlich, es könnten Nomen im Singular oder unbestimmte Artikel auftauchen.

Als Faustregel gilt: Gibt es irgendwie die Möglichkeit, dass man den Artikel in einer sinnvollen Fortsetzung der Aufzählung bräuchte, sollte er nicht weggelassen werden.

Answer (score -2):

zu deiner Frage:

**Die Sensorik** und **die 1G Hyperlandschaft** sind grammatikalisch gesehen Substantive.

**Die** steht immer für die weibliche Form und **Der** bezeichnet
die männliche Form.
Substantive haben immer einen Artikel davor.
Artikel sind **Der** oder **Die** oder **Das**.

Beispiel:

Der Mann
Der Baum
Der Weg
Der Stein
Der Wagen

**Die Sensorik**

Die Frau

Die Landschaft

Die Straße

**Die 1G Hyperlandschaft**

Das Haus
Das Auto
Das Kind

Comment: Nein, Artikel ist nicht zwingend. "Wir gehen über Stock und Stein, alle zusammen, Mann und Frau und Kind." Der Sinn ist anders, wenn ich schreibe "Wir gehen über den Stock und den Stein, alle zusammen, der Mann, die Frau und das Kind" (ebenso auch mit den entsprechenden Nomen im Plural)